# NetCDF time aggregation using R stars package

Tags: r, netcdf, spatio-temporal-data, stars

I have a monthly temperature netCDF dataset with aprox 20 years and I'd like to calculate a monthly climatology (average of all Jan, Feb, Mar...).

I know I can do this with `stackapply` from package `raster`. But I'm trying to learn the package `stars`. I tried using the `aggregate` function but I'm not able to figure out how to set the `by` argument correctly to apply the `mean` function to each month.

This is what my dataset looks like:

```
stars object with 3 dimensions and 1 attribute
attribute(s), summary of first 1e+05 cells:
 Tavg_monthly_UT_Brazil_v2_19800101_20151231.nc 
 Min.   :18.11                                  
 1st Qu.:25.00                                  
 Median :26.36                                  
 Mean   :25.85                                  
 3rd Qu.:26.85                                  
 Max.   :29.83                                  
 NA's   :56236                                  
dimension(s):
     from  to offset delta  refsys point                    values    
x       1 168 -74.25  0.25      NA    NA                      NULL [x]
y       1 162   6.25 -0.25      NA    NA                      NULL [y]
time    1 432     NA    NA POSIXct    NA 1980-01-16,...,2015-12-16
```

Is `aggregate` the correct function to use? I also tried `group_by` but that does not work for `stars` objects.

Answer (score 4):

I was able to calculate the monthly climatology. But I'm not sure it's the best approach.

```
monthly_mean <- function(month) {
  nc_time_series %>%
    filter(lubridate::month(time) == month) %>%
    st_apply(c(1,2), mean, na.rm = TRUE)
}

a <- lapply(1:12, monthly_mean) # calculate for each month

climate <- do.call(c, a) %>% # join list ellements
  merge() %>% # convert attribute to dimension
  setNames("Mean T") %>% # fix attribute name
  st_set_dimensions(3, values = 1:12) %>% # fix dimension size
  st_set_dimensions(names = c('x', 'y', 'month')) # set dimension name
```

Answer (score 2):

I have added an example on how to aggregate along the time dimension in time steps.
See this link to the [stars-github-repo](https://github.com/r-spatial/stars/blob/master/R/aggregate.R).
For completeness I've copied it here:

```
# aggregate time dimension in format Date
tif = system.file("tif/L7_ETMs.tif", package = "stars")
t1 = as.Date("2018-07-31")
x = read_stars(c(tif, tif, tif, tif), along = list(time = c(t1, t1+1, t1+2, t1+3)), 
               RasterIO = list(nXOff = c(1), 
                               nYOff = c(1), 
                               nXSize = 50, 
                               nYSize = 50, 
                               bands = c(1:6)))
st_get_dimension_values(x, "time")
x_agg_time = aggregate(x, by = t1 + c(0, 2, 4), FUN = max)

# aggregate time dimension in format Date - interval
by_t = "2 days"
x_agg_time2 = aggregate(x, by = by_t, FUN = max)
st_get_dimension_values(x_agg_time2, "time")
x_agg_time - x_agg_time2

# aggregate time dimension in format POSIXct
x = st_set_dimensions(x, 4, values = as.POSIXct(c("2018-07-31",
                                                  "2018-08-01",
                                                  "2018-08-02",
                                                  "2018-08-03")),
                      names = "time")
by_t = as.POSIXct(c("2018-07-31", "2018-08-02"))
x_agg_posix = aggregate(x, by = by_t, FUN = max)
st_get_dimension_values(x_agg_posix, "time")
x_agg_time - x_agg_posix
```

Hope you can work off of this.

Added after comment:

```
# aggregate non continuous time dimension
x = read_stars(c(tif, tif, tif, tif), 
               along = list(time = c(t1, t1+10, t1+365, t1+700)), 
               RasterIO = list(nXOff = c(1), 
                               nYOff = c(1), 
                               nXSize = 50, 
                               nYSize = 50, 
                               bands = c(1:6)))
st_get_dimension_values(x, "time")
x_agg_time = aggregate(x, by = "1 year", FUN = max)
st_get_dimension_values(x_agg_time, "time")
```

Comment: Cool, I was not aware I could do that. But how about aggregating non-continuous intervals. For example, Jan-1980 + Jan-1981 + Jan-1982. Can it be done?

Comment: I updated the answer. I think this is what you are trying to do.

Comment: Thanks. But I'm not sure if I did not understand your answer or if  I did not explain well what I was trying to do. Say I have 10 years of monthly data. I want to end up with only 12 images, the first  being the average off all January images (all years). The second is the mean off all February and so on.

Comment: Please see https://github.com/r-spatial/stars/issues/134 for a new, alternative way to do this with stars.